# Should @s Highlight for the Person Being Pinged

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So there's an inconsistency that's always bothered me:

Whenever someone @s someone in a comment, the @ shows up as just normal text. This is definitely not the effect that I've seen used on any other forum/site (of this nature).

---

**Here's the way it is:**
[image: Pre-way-it-should-be]

**And here's the way it should be seen (as the person being "pinged"):**
[image]

---

1. The reason I believe this to be necessary is that comment feeds are often horrendous, and if you want to see someone is talking to you, highlighting the @ from the ping would make it a lot easier to respond to comments directed towards you. Especially here in meta, it's often seen that comments get rather messy.
2. Another supporting argument is that it should match the theme of the site, which highlights the username that sends a comment blue.

---

## Comments

> One issue could be users who share the same screen name would you want to highlight it for all of them?

No, the highlight would only highlight for the last user with that username who commented. Obviously, there are some flaws in that system, but I'm of course, open to suggestions.

---

Now I by no means am suggesting that this edit is necessary. But I do seem to edge towards this as it's sort of seen as the standard... I appreciate you guys' time and comments and don't go too hard on me, I'm new to meta.

Tell me if I'm on the wrong site or something

Comment: We have a defined protocol and guideline for [tag:feature-request]s. Please adapt your question accordingly.

Comment: One issue could be users who share the same screen name would you want to highlight it for all of them?

Comment: Also note that `@ed` is usually refered as _pinged_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That link doesn't work for me, oof

Comment: @FeaturedSpace Sorry: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info

Comment: Okay, I've updated.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is not like a lot of "forums" or other sites. Some of us actually pride ourselves on that. Among other things, keeping a professional tone in writing is important. As such, I've removed the emoji. Also, comments are not supposed to get that long; they are supposed to be reserved for gaining clarification on posts, not for chit-chat, so there should be little need for keeping track of long threads.

Comment: Yeah, I know but they end up being used for that purpose regardless. Any meta post on here makes that much clear.

Comment: I'm downvoting because I don't think such a feature would be useful.

Comment: This feature is not useless but It doesn't add up anything. If the user is pinged they are sent a notification. What would highlighting do?

Comment: "which highlights the username that sends a comment blue" no, it doesn't. That highlighting indicates the person who wrote the question under which the comment (or the answer on which the comment was made) was posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I'm not sure about how useful this would be as an official feature, it's relatively simple to implement this sort of thing on your own machine with a userscript, if you so wish. (You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9IRC.png)

Code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Stack Highlight Comment Pings
// @author           CertainPerformance
// @version          1.0
// @include          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @include          https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant            none
// ==/UserScript==

const usernameWithoutSpaces = window.decodeURI(
  document.querySelector('.my-profile').href.match(/[^/]+$/)[0]
)
  .replace(/-/g, '');
// Make a regex to match text like "@user" which is not within an HTML attribute
// Usernames with odd characters like ʇ̲ or π are hard to make a simple pattern for
// except on very recent browsers with unicode character class support
// so construct the pattern dynamically with a character set instead
const pattern = new RegExp(`@([${usernameWithoutSpaces}\\w]+)(?![^<>]*>)`, 'i');
const checkedSpans = new Set();
const checkSpan = (commentSpan) => {
  if (checkedSpans.has(commentSpan)) {
    return;
  }
  checkedSpans.add(commentSpan);
  commentSpan.innerHTML = commentSpan.innerHTML.replace(
    pattern,
    (match, nameStart) => (
      usernameWithoutSpaces.startsWith(nameStart.toLowerCase())
      ? `<span style="background-color:yellow">@${nameStart}</span>`
      : match // change nothing
    )
  );
};
// could be made more elegant with MutationObservers and click listeners
const checkAll = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('li.comment .comment-copy').forEach(checkSpan);
};
setInterval(checkAll, 100);
```

It'll have some false positives (eg `@bob` would highlight for a user with a name of `bobjoe` who is not involved in the comment thread), but those should be rare, and weeding them out entirely would be significantly more complicated.

If you want a style other than `background-color:yellow`, feel free to customize.

Should work for users with unusual characters in their name as well.

Comment: I like this answer. While I don't really have an issue with the usernames not highlighting that badly, I appreciate the effort that you put into this answer. Very nice.